# php ide that supports zend debugger or how can netbeans support zend

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm using netbeans and i need to use zend debugger because it can support multi hosts and not like xdebug that supports only one user at a time.
I'm looking for a php ide that can support sftp, zend deubbger and can communicate with the microsoft team server, preferably supports css xfire and i need it to be free.
has anyone familiarised with such an IDE?
if not, then how do i add support for zend debugger and team server in netbeans?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm usind zend debugger with Eclipse PDT http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/ and it works fine.

You can use SCP,SFTP too in Eclipse and a plugin for Microsoft Team Server is available too.

Comment: how do you import a project from a remote server using sftp? in netbeans you just import it and everytime you save it uploads the file into the server. and does the tfs support free? i've noticed that it costs alot. even the plugin that is offered by microsoft cost

Comment: Yes you can import a remote project : http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t88137.rhtml